# Array Formula to Ignore Rows Where Value Exists

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This array formula works beautifully for what I need:

```
=IF(S12="","","Fastest Loop Completed in "&TEXT(MIN(IF((S12:S1048576<>"")*(R12:R1048576<>""),S12:S1048576-R12:R1048576)),"[m]:ss"))
```

I've since added Column U that will either be blank or have a text string of "A" or "B". I want to update the above formula to perform the same function and continue to include rows where Column U is either blank or "A", but ignore rows where Column U contains "B". I've fiddled with `AND(...,U<>"B")`, but am not making any progress. This formula is just giving me *"Fastest Loop Completed in 0:00"*:

```
=IF(S12="","","Fastest Loop Completed in "&TEXT(MIN(IF(AND((S12:S1048576<>"")*(R12:R1048576<>""),U12:U1048576<>"B"),S12:S1048576-R12:R1048576)),"[m]:ss"))
```

On a side note, is there a cleaner/lighter way to do `(S12:S1048576<>"")*(R12:R1048576<>"")` to accomplish the same result and have it only check where Column A isn't blank, without having it mindlessly looking at all rows? I.e., "where Column A isn't blank, Column U is not equal to "B" *and* there is a value in both R and S, then find the fastest time." The sheet could possibly be run with just a few rows or, I anticipate, up to tens of thousands of rows, so it needs to be flexible. I don't expect anyone to ever run 1 million rows (ha, I say that now...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the formula to work by converting the strings to numbers within an `IF()` statement:

```
=IF(S12="","","Fastest Loop Completed in "&TEXT(MIN(IF((S12:S1048576<>"")*(R12:R1048576<>"")*(IF(U12:U1048576="B","",1)<>""),S12:S1048576-R12:R1048576)),"[m]:ss"))
```

Still interested to know if there is a better way than using an IF() to accomplish this as well as a cleaner/lighter way to only check rows that have data.